# LiteDB: Are Projections supported?

Tags: c#, mongodb, projection, litedb, nosql

I'm trying to evaluate whether I can use **LiteDB** for one of my projects. I love **MongoDB** for its query capabilities and for the **projections**. See: [Mongo Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

The problem is, that I want to use a database that doesn't need a dedicated server process, so I looked out for **[LiteDB](http://www.litedb.org/)** as it stores the database in just one file and has a similar approach like **MongoDB**.

Until now I haven't found documentation about the possibility to perform projections while querying. So does someone have experience with this and can tell me if that is possible?